# never get the opportunity to enter a string input. C++

Tags: c++, string, input, output

I am trying to read two strings from the users and output them. 
If I type in "Micheal Jordan" for the first input, the program won't give me a chance to enter my second string.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "cstring"

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  string name;
  string dessert;

  cout << "Enter your name: \n";
  cin >> name;

  cout << "Enter your favorite dessert: \n";
  cin >> dessert;

  cout << "I have some delicious " << dessert << " for you, " << name << "." << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
./a.out 
Enter your name: 
Micheal Jordan
Enter your favorite dessert: 
I have some delicious Jordan for you, Micheal.
```

The code works fine if I input a name without a space.

```
./a.out 
Enter your name: 
MichealJordan
Enter your favorite dessert: 
Cake
I have some delicious Cake for you, MichealJordan.
```

So I am guessing it's the space that creates this problem, can you guys tell me how to fix it? And I am also wondering what's going on with the space. 
Thank you!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

std::getline(cin, name); get the input untill the end of the line;

also if you still have the same problem you can just make the user type the first name then the last name but hopefully getline will work :)